# How to keep back rear display off on D7200

Tags: nikon, display

**UPDATE:**
Temporary solution for this: Map the ISO button(which I use most) to **video recording button(that red button)**

---

All:

Just got my D7200, because the back display is power consuming, I really want to keep it off, but the situation is:

When I try to adjust WB/QUAL/ISO, the back display alway turns on, I wonder how can I only use the shoulder LCD(the info there most time is enough to me) but keep the back display off(or only manually turn on when I need it)?

Thanks,

Comment: as far as I remember, in normal use, d7200's battery should last thousands of clicks. Are you sure you are not spending minute adjusting settings every shot? I am just trying to point to possible real problem

Comment: @aaaaaa  Thanks. By "power consuming", I mean it is relative heavy, but not like it eats battery like crazy.  The battery is good, I mean if I can keep the display off, then there could be more power saved.

Comment: so there is no real problem, as in "i am missing shots because battery runs out"?

Comment: @aaaaaa Yeah, I just want to save more power. But where did U quote that "i am missing shots because battery runs out"?

Answer (score 1):

My D800 or D300 don't do that, but they have top buttons for those controls, and the top LCD (and viewfinder) show what you're doing then.

What does this rear LCD show then?  The Info screen? Isn't it showing what you are setting?  Not the same as disable, but you should be able to turn the Info screen off faster by tapping the info button, or by lightly tapping the shutter button. Tapping the shutter button turns off any display immediately. You probably have to finish your adjustment first.

Image Review in the Playback menu can disable the rear LCD showing the previous shot, but this sounds different.

There is a D9 menu for Info display, that says Manual or Auto.  The manual is not detailed, that may not be On/Off, it might only be brightness?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, as u said, I am currently just tap info button to turn it off which is pretty annoying. And Yes, the info on rear display has more detail, but most time I do not need them, that is why I want to only manually turn it on.

Comment: This was true on the D90, D7000 generation cameras too (and up in models)

Around the D7100 / D810 I believe they shrank the top LCD slightly so certain buttons that used to show on the top LCD only by default didn't fit, forcing the back screen to show the changes. 

I hate this too, because night shooting. White on black helps somewhat...